# Using Jackson annotations with inherited class

Tags: java, android, orm, annotations, jackson

I'm developing an Android App where I'm deserializing JSON with the Jackson Annotation API.

It worked really well until I tried to include the AndroidActive ORM, which required your POJO to inherit from the Model class (https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/blob/master/src/com/activeandroid/Model.java).

My JSON is deserialized in an asyncTask as such :

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
try {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    rootJsonObj = mapper.readValue(reader, MyPojo.class);
} catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

A quick look at my pogo :

```
@Table(name = "RootRecipes") //AndroidActive annotation
public class RootRecipes extends Model { 

    @JsonProperty("deleted") //Jackson annotation
    @Column(name = "deleted") //AndroidActive annotation
    public ArrayList<Number> deleted; 

    @JsonProperty("meta")
    @Column(name = "meta")
    public Meta meta; 

    @JsonProperty("objects")
    @Column(name = "objects")
    public ArrayList<Objects> objects;
```

The json is very large more than 2mo but the structure is the following :

```
{"deleted": [107981, 107982, 107995, 107999, 108012, 108014], 
"meta": {"is_anonymous": true, "latest": 1405555349, "limit": 1000, "next": null, "offset": 0, "page": 1, "pages": 1, "previous": null, "total_count": 20}, 
"objects": [<more objects>]}
```

The error given to me is :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Instantiation of [simple type, class com.example.app.json.MyPojo] value failed: null
```

As soon as I removed the inheritance from Model the parsing is working normally.
I can't figure out the reason of this error.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us your `JSON` which you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: I've added its structure, it's very large. Yet, the parsing with Jackson is working great as long as MyPojo doesn't extend Model.

Comment: OK, thanks. I see that this model class contains elements which belongs to Android world. I think that this is a reason why `Jackson` is not able to deserialize and instantiate this object. You should to decouple Android's properties from real data.

Comment: Thank you for interest. I've looked here and there and I'm probably not familiar enough with Jackson to decouple those properties. Do you have any guess on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should created new `POJO` classes for working with `JSON` which are decoupled from Android world(I mean, they can not have properties, parents which come from Android packages). It could look like this:

```
class JsonRootRecipes {

    @JsonProperty("deleted")
    public List<Number> deleted;

    @JsonProperty("meta")
    public JsonMeta meta;

    @JsonProperty("objects")
    public List<Object> objects;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class JsonMeta {

    @JsonProperty("is_anonymous")
    private boolean anonymous;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

// another POJOs decoupled from Android classes.
```

Now, you have to create a service class which will be able to parse `JSON` and convert `JsonPojo` classes to your Android `POJO` classes. Pseudocode:

```
class JsonService {

    public RootRecipes parseJson(json) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

        JsonRootRecipes jsonRootRecipes = mapper.readValue(json, JsonRootRecipes.class);

        RootRecipes rootRecipes = null; //convert jsonRootRecipes to RootRecipes

        return rootRecipes;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's unfortuneatly what I feared most, having to double all my json related POJO :'( Thank you for you time and interest. If I happen to find a better way to do it, I'll add it.